# Raspberry Pi + omxplayer-wraper - запуск видео файлов в нужном порядке по нажатию кнопок

Tags: python, видео, raspberry-pi, python-2.7, raspbian

Пытаюсь запускать видео файлы с Raspberry Pi из питона.
Для этого использую [omxplayer-wrapper](https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper).

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм:

1. В начале работы программы проигрывается файл a.mp4
2. При нажатии кнопки 1, a.mp4 останавливается и включается b.mp4. Когда он заканчивается, снова включается a.mp4
3. При нажатии кнопки 2, a.mp4 останавливается и включается c.mp4. Когда он заканчивается, снова включается a.mp4

Алгоритм работает, но наблюдаются следующие недостатки:

1. После того как заканчивает проигрываться файл b.mp4 перед запуском a.mp4 виден рабочий стол (примерно 1 секунду)
2. После того как заканчивает проигрываться файл c.mp4 перед запуском a.mp4 виден рабочий стол уже больше времени (примерно 10-12 секунд)

Как правильно осуществить эту задачу?

Привожу набросок кода:

```
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
from time import sleep

playerA = OMXPlayer('path/to/a.mp4', args=['-b', '--loop'])
playerB = OMXPlayer('path/to/b.mp4', args=['-b'])
playerC = OMXPlayer('path/to/c.mp4', args=['-b'])

playerA.play()

while True:
    if Button1PressedFlag==True: #set in interrupt
        Button1PressedFlag=False
        playerA.pause()
        playerB.play()
        while playerB.is_playing():
            sleep(0.2)
        playerB.quit()
        playerA.play()
    if Button2PressedFlag==True: #set in interrupt
        Button2PressedFlag=False
        playerA.pause()
        playerC.play()
        while playerC.is_playing():
            sleep(0.2)
        playerC.quit()
        playerA.play()
```

UPD:
Вчера вечером проверил - вообще жесть.
`is_playing` то работает, то не работает.
Там где не работает `is_playing()`, работает функция `playback_status(),` хотя она используется в `is_playing()`..
`quit()` то убивает процесс, то нет.
`stop()` то останавливает проигрыватель, то убивает процесс
Каша страшная..
Решил проблему грязным трюком:
1.запускаю видео
2. беру его продолжительность и вставляю в `sleep()`
3. после слипа убиваю видео
Если надо переключить видео, то переключение происходит в прерывании от кнопки.
Кажется работает... Но не красиво как-то... :(

Comment: Я предполагаю, что одной из проблем может быть буферизация (кэширование) видео перед проигрыванием. Это зависит и от дистрибутива, и от конкретных настроек. 
Пробовали вместо `quit` использовать `stop`, чтобы не перезапускать плеер лишний раз и не тратить ресурсы и так слабенького компьютера? Хорошо бы еще отловить, где именно в коде происходит задержка. Еще, чтобы разгрузить устройство, можно запускать приложение без DE, тем более, я так понимаю, нужен режим "киоска", рабочий стол ни к чему.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу новую информацию.
А скажите, как можно без графической оболочки запустить Raspberry?
Или кажется я видел там какую-то настройку...

Comment: У вас Raspbian? Если да, то [с помощью](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server/1320) `raspi-config` можно настроить init-level, в котором ОС будет загружаться без загрузки `X`-ов и `DE`. А затем уже вручную можно запускать `X`-ы и ваше приложение. [Здесь](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107319), например, можно почитать, как запустить GUI-приложение без графического окружения.

Comment: А вообще, необходимо разобраться в "каше", чтобы понять, в чем проблема. С питанием RPi всё в порядке? Кстати, на SO есть спец. [раздел](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) для вопросов о RPi.

Comment: О! Спасибо большое! Почитаю...
Да, этот вопрос запостил уже и там, и на основном форуме Raspberry.

Comment: Может поискать плеер с DBUS api?

Comment: @JK_Action  omxplayer-wrapper это и есть DBUS api

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю костыли в виде вычисления времени завершения и запуске новой функции за 1-2 секунды(ну или милисекунды)
Однако, остаётся проблема с постановкой первого видео\второго видео на паузу... (модуль не имеет функций вычисления оставшегося\проигранного времени)

Я бы провёл эксперимент с запуском плеера через командную строку (возможно использовать subprocess для экономии времени запуска командной строки), то есть завершение видео, влечёт завершение команды (хотя мб в настройках плеера это можно обойти ввиде плейлиста).

Answer (score 0):

1. Используй один плеер. Просто меняй файл в нем. Позицию файла А можно сохранить и возобновить перемоткой.
2. Используй один плеер вместо трех. А ещё если нет рабочего стола - то и нет проблем. плеер можно запускать в голых иксах.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу 2 варианта решения проблемы. Или использовать pause/load

```
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
from gpiozero import Button

player = OMXPlayer('path/to/a.mp4', args=['-b', '--loop'])
button1 = Button(1)
button2 = Button(2)

player.play()

while True:
    if button1.is_pressed:
        player.pause()
        player.load('path/to/b.mp4')
        player.play()
    elif button2.is_pressed:
        player.pause()
        player.load('path/to/c.mp4')
        player.play()
```

Или использовать прелоад

```
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
from gpiozero import Button
from threading import Thread

playerA = OMXPlayer('path/to/a.mp4', args=['-b', '--loop'])
playerB = OMXPlayer('path/to/b.mp4', args=['-b'])
playerC = OMXPlayer('path/to/c.mp4', args=['-b'])

current_player = playerA
next_player = playerB

def load_next_video(player, video_path):
    player.load(video_path)

load_thread = Thread(target=load_next_video, args=(next_player, 'path/to/b.mp4'))
load_thread.start()

button1 = Button(1)
button2 = Button(2)

current_player.play()

while True:
    if button1.is_pressed:
        current_player.pause()
        next_player.pause()
        current_player, next_player = next_player, current_player
        load_thread = Thread(target=load_next_video, args=(next_player, 'path/to/b.mp4'))
        load_thread.start()
        current_player.play()
    elif button2.is_pressed:
        current_player.pause()
        next_player.pause()
        current_player, next_player = next_player, current_player
        load_thread = Thread(target=load_next_video, args=(next_player, 'path/to/c.mp4'))
        load_thread.start()
        current_player.play()
```

девайса нет, проверить не могу. Накидал по старой памяти, надеюсь будет работать.